# Adding TextChanged and KeyPressed Event Handlers to EditText makes OnBackPressed not hitting

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have been working on an app where there are 3 activities (let's say A, B, C)

1. A calls B using StartActivity(typeof(B))
2. B calls C using StartActivity(typeof(C)) and finish itself using
   this.finish()
3. C has a full screen EditText inside a LinearLayout. C has also overridden
   OnBackPressed where it calls this.finish() to complete itself and navigates
   back to A [as A is still in the BackStack]. Inside OnCreate Method of C,
   EventHandlers of EditText have been added TextChanged event and KeyPressed
   Event like below:

```
public void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceBundle) 
{
    base.OnCreate(SavedInstanceBundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EditTextLayout);
    EditText editText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText);
    //ADDING EVENT HANDLERS FOR EDITTEXT'S TEXTCHANGED AND KEYPRESSED EVENTS
    editText.TextChanged += editText_TextChanged;
    editText.KeyPressed += editText_KeyPressed;
}

private void editText_TextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
}

private void editText_KeyPressed (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
{
}

public override void OnBackPressed() 
{
    base.OnBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

The problem here is that when the eventhandler code exist, the OnBackPressed is
never executed when Hardware back is pressed. But, when the adding event
handler code is removed for both the event, eventually OnBackPressed starts
working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine if the user pressed the Back key in your KeyPressed event handler:

```
private void editText_KeyPressed (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back)
    {
        this.Finish();
        e.Handled = true;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! this works... i thought it to be a bug in xamarin at first place, but now this works...